# How to open new intent when webview go out of my website

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

I'm making an Android App with Java in Android Studio for my website using webview, but i've a lot of links which go out of website. How can i detect if link redirect from [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) to [www.anotherwebsite.com](http://www.anotherwebsite.com) and open it in another page intent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

and create and inner class

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    return false;
   
}
```

}

You can find complete documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#java)

Comment: But, if i want to go to another page in my website like www.mywebsite.com/anotherpage without go out of webview? Just for pages different than www.mywebsite.com/...

Comment: I have updated the code, please have a look.

Comment: Appeared just return false inside the public boolean

Comment: Try to implement it as it is. If not working, please share your code as well so that I may explain the specific change required.